# Не создаются классы сущностей в ADO model WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ado.net, ef

Пробую создать ADO model из базы данных, но классы сущностей не создаются, не могу разобраться почему, вот скриншот соединения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в модели создается пустой файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ADO.NET и EF это два разных подхода, где первый, это условный "низкоуровневый" слой на котором базируется второй. Для начала выберите что-то одно, а затем уже решайте поставленную задачу. Если выбираете EF, то я вам советую почитать про миграции, сделайте просто класс, опишите им свою таблицу, и запустите миграцию, получите в итоге базу, которую будет легко обновить или в случае чего откатить обратно.

Comment: ну как мне тогда починить ADO

Comment: Распространённая ошибка: подключение не к той базе данных. Возможно, имеются две БД с названием Test, расположенные в разных местах. В той, к которой подключились - пусто. Поэтому и модели пустые.

Comment: нет, других баз данных с таким же названием. пробовал и с другими базами ничего не выходитт